# How to add nonce (CSP) to allow inline js/styles on Angular SPA pages served by Spring boot Java Application?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-maps, google-analytics, content-security-policy

I have an Angular SPA application served by Angular boot Java application with a strict CSP Policy in place.

I've added the below config to allow Google Analytics and Maps to work -

```
"img-src 'self' data: maps.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com *.ggpht.com https://www.google-analytics.com"
"connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com *.a2develop.com"
"script-src 'self' maps.googleapis.com www.googletagmanager.com
```

Analytics seems to work, but google Maps seems to apply inline styles, so that does not work

Errors

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' maps.googleapis.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-a2VR/Wq1VPr0+3GRY+lEmAQm7wjwwnDtPpcCs2zTrw='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Are there any methods to add a nonce to the Angular SPA application served by the Java Spring boot app?

Answer (score 1):

Of couse you can manage `'nonce-value'` into CSP HTTP header using Spring Security built-in filters.
But SPA uses meta tag CSP and also SPA are not compatible with `nonce`.

CSP spec requшres that server MUST generate a fresh value for the `'nonce-value'` at random and independently each time it transmits a policy (each page loading). But the SPA loads the page once, and then just updates parts of it instead of loading a new page.

Therefore, the meta tag with `nonce` will remain the same. Changing meta tag CSP with the script will no effect, because previous policy will be in force and a second one will be added.